# how to get the min-id object from coredata?

Tags: ios, core-data

i use coredata in my project to store some data;

i can get the all the object from context like follows

```
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"TestItem"];
    NSArray *items = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    NSLog(@"got entities count %d", [items count]);
    for(TestItem *item in items){
        NSLog(@" entity id:%@, name:%@, date:%@", item.id, item.name, item.date);
    }
```

but how to get one object that has the minimum id??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can sort descriptor to the fetch and limit it to 1 object, and I think you can also use tricks like session 137 (WWDC video 2010) to add a subquery: `SUBQUERY(things, $thing).id.@min == XXX` if you need a particular one.